# different .bashrc files for different login nodes?

Tags: linux, bash, login

Can I have different `.bashrc` files loading when logging into different nodes that share the same home dir?

This is, I am mostly interested to loading different PATH directories when logging as bash, depending on the different Linux nodes I log into? For example, if I log into bash in machine abc-01, I would like to have a given `.bashrc` loaded, but when I log into abc-02, that uses the same /home/username directory, I would like to use a different `.bashrc`. How can I go about doing that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can put things like:

```
if [ $HOSTNAME = "abc-01" ]; then
        sh ~/.bashrc_abc01
fi


if [ $HOSTNAME = "abc-02" ]; then
         sh ~/.bashrc_abc02
fi
```

in `.bashrc` and create different scripts `.bashrc_abc01`, `.bashrc_abc02` with the actual commands. Or if there are not that many commands, you can put them in the if statements.

Comment: +1 or do something like `. ./.bashrc-$(hostname)`

Comment: yes, that's shorter